# Entity Framework records a collection in reverse order

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I try to save into my DB an object containing a collection of objects.

Entities are defined in model classes the way it should be AFAIK:

```
public partial class Item
    {
       ...
       public virtual ICollection<Subitem> Subitems{ get; set; }
    }
```

Most of the time, the collection is saved in the order of my collection.
I mean item.Subitems[0] will be saved before item.Subitems[1], before item.Subitems[2]...

But in a single use case, for any reason, they are saved the reverse way:
item.Subitems[N max] saved before ...., saved before item.Subitems[1] saved before item.Subitems[0].

The weird thing is, in this use case, I set my collection just like in other use cases and save it just the same way:

```
public MyMethod (ICollection<Subitem> subitems) // I assert that the collection is in the order I want here
{
  foreach (var item in subitems)  // I assert that the collection is in the order I want here
        {
          Subitem subitem= CreateItem(item);
          item.Subitems.Add(subitem);
        }
}
```

and later in the code the usual:

```
myContext.SaveChanges() // I assert that the collection is in the order I want here
```

We use transactions although it shouldn't changes anything AFAIK.

I have also tried instead:

```
List<Subitem> subitemsList = new ();
 foreach (var item in subitems)  // I assert that the collection is in the order I want here
        {
          Subitem subitem= CreateItem(item);
          //item.Subitems.Add(subitem);
          subitemsList.Add(subitem);
        }
 item.Subitems =subitemsList ; // I assert that the collection is in the order I want here
```

Why would EF sometimes save the collection elements in their reverse order?

My patch is to do after I set my collection in the use case causing the issue:

```
item.Subitems = item.Subitems.Reverse();
```

But of course, I hate to let this line in the solution.

Comment: This is not a EF issue.  It depends on the DataBase.  SQL Server is a multi-threaded database and doing the same query multiple times will get results in different order unless you use a Order By.  Since EF is not doing the query (it is done in the database) the order is done by the database.  Some databases will return data in the same order that data is entered like a table.  When you are dealing with a multi-thread query order is random.

Comment: yeah, but all use cases but one ALWAYS record the subitems in the collection order.
One single use case ALWAYS record the subitems in the reverse collection order.

Comment: I guess most people wouldn't even care about the order here - most databases are fundamentally unordered - so... it simply might not be a design goal to care about, as long as the correct data is stored. Just to be clear: what mechanism are you using to determine that it was stored in the reverse order? Do you have a trace running so you can see the `insert` statements? or are you issuing a `select` afterwards? or...?

Comment: @Marc Gravel:
Well, it breaks my unit tests as I have tests based on the collection order being pre-determined :)

To determine the order, I refer to one of the subitems properties being a string.
I add subitem having property value = "1" , next item "2" then "3".
And in the concerned use case, the higher PK will be set to the record with property "1" instead of "3" in all other use cases.

Comment: @A.D. SQL, the language, doesn't guarantee any order without an ORDER BY clause. There's no `ALWAYS` at all. The database is free to return rows as they come without an `ORDER BY`. Even without parallelization, even with clustered indexes, a hash operation *will* change the order of results.

Comment: @A.D. `it breaks my unit tests` on the contrary, the unit tests found a bug - the missing `ORDER BY`. You need to decide now - do you care about the order? Add an `ORDER BY`. If not, modify the tests to *not* care about order. Enumerable operations like `Except` or `Contains` don't care about order.

Comment: @A.D. execution plans are affected by data statistics (as they should) so different data can result in different execution plans and different order for the same query. Cached data can be returned faster than data that's still on disk. The [different types of physical JOIN operations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/joins?view=sql-server-ver15) can affect the order as well. For SQL, both `item` and `subitem` are just tables, and the physical JOIN used to retrieve them will depend on indexes and statistics, not entity relations

Comment: Have you tried? foreach(var item in subitems.OrderBy(x))

Answer (score 0):

+1 Panagiotis, this exposes a bad unit test / code assumption. If order is important, the code / test must provide an `OrderBy` clause to ensure predictable, repeatable behaviour.

The root of your problem as far as the test assertion after SaveChanges is likely this:

```
public virtual ICollection<Subitem> Subitems{ get; set; }
```

This tells EF that SubItems is a simple set of references. EF works with proxies so unless it needs to conform to a particular interface it will optimize based on what it's told it needs to conform to. `ICollection` only enforces that Subitems is a collection that can be added & removed from. Changing it to `IList` ***may*** provide the behaviour you are expecting within the scope of the test, or outline a difference in behaviour between two similar objects:

```
public virtual IList<Subitem> Subitems{ get; set; }
```

`IList` enforces that elements can be accessed by index, so an implied order should be maintained. This doesn't mean however that data re-loaded from the DbContext etc. will maintain that order, and it may not even guarantee that the data is inserted in that order. If an order is important then your code and tests should *always* provide an `OrderBy` clause, whether defined as `ICollection` or `IList`.

A general code rule is that any code that uses `ElementAt`, `First`/`FirstOrDefault`, or similar order-dependent methods should always have an `OrderBy`/`OrderByDescending` clause.

Comment: swapping the model structure as per your suggestion to IList
did not solve the problem.

The collection comes from a Json.
The required order is set by endusers filling the json and is not based on any property of Subitem class.
I do not want to add a column into the DB table just to be able to use OrderBy when needed.
I suppose that I can create a partial class including a NumIOrder property that I set after receiving the json and before saving the collection.
Si I could use OIrderby NumOrder without having to alter my DB table.
I am surprised we do not find a more convenient way.

Comment: My second idea was to use a .Net existing class implementing IOrderedCollection and hope that  it would make it but it does not seem that MS provides any such implementation.